# can i used iPhone story board for iPad?

Tags: ios, xcode6

I have developed app for both iPad and iPhone, but it was rejected by Apple because it is not working on iPad. After i received the crash report, i cross checked in Xcode, Now my all screens are set in 'autolayout' view. In the settings i have assigned the iPhone storyboard for iPad. As shown below: fig1 for the iPhone settings and fig2 for iPad.
[image]

[image]

Is this configuration correct ? Will it be approved by Apple ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need a separate storyboard files for both. Here's a tutorial link: https://irawd.wordpress.com/2014/10/21/xcode-6-separate-storyboard-for-ipad-and-iphone/

Comment: As previous comment, you must have separate storyboards files or you must have one storyboard with Size Classes enabled.